# What is the default color and font for input placeholders

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know what is the default color and font and size for placeholders for inputs and textareas?

```
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Select data" class="form-control"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Use a color picker tool.  I believe it varies by browser, also.  In your screenshot, it's `#8e8e8e`

Comment: Confirmed it is #8e8e8e

Comment: This setting is browser-specific and is not defined in any standard. For most browsers that support dome kind of dev tools (like Chrome) you can use those to check what colors / fonts the elements are rendered with by default. Though you must be aware of that this behavior might be changed. More then that I can't imagine any real world scenario when you need to know that.

Comment: @cale_b post an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Depending on your application / need, you could use a color picker tool, or you could use your Browser's developer console, to be sure.  But...

The *default* input placeholder color varies by browser.

In your screenshot, it's `#8e8e8e`

Some examples by browser:
In Chrome (Mac) it's `#a9a9a9`
in Firefox (Mac) it's `#777777`

Bootstrap 3 does define a "default" placeholder color, which you can see by inspecting the CSS a variety of ways - below is from the CSS directly (For Bootstrap v3.3.7):

```
.form-control::-moz-placeholder{
    color:#999;
    opacity:1
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder{
    color:#999
}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color:#999
}
```

So - Bootstrap 3 defines the default placeholder color as `#999`.  (For reference, Bootstrap 4 defines the default placeholder color as `#636c72`).

Answer (score 1):

If you open up `bootstrap.css` file, and `ctrl`+`f` (find) and search for "form-control" and look for placeholder you will find:

```
  .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
```

According to bootstraps [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/):

> Bootstrap's global default font-size is 14px, with a line-height of 1.428. This is applied to the  and all paragraphs. In addition,
>
> (paragraphs) receive a bottom margin of half their computed line-height (10px by default).

[link to color](http://www.colorhexa.com/999999)